# GCC 11.x vexing-parse + inconsistent error (redeclaration as different symbol type), is it a GCC bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, gcc11

The following code compiles with no problems [from GCC 4.7.1 up to but not including GCC 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/4fvna4vn5):

```c++
constexpr int SomeValue = 0;

void test () {
    void (SomeValue) ();
}
```

On GCC 11.x it fails with:

```
<source>:4:23: error: 'void SomeValue()' redeclared as different kind of entity
    4 |     void (SomeValue) ();
      |                       ^
<source>:1:15: note: previous declaration 'constexpr const int SomeValue'
    1 | constexpr int SomeValue = 0;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
```

But the error "redeclared as different kind of entity" seems strange to me: Ambiguous parsing possibilities aside, the scope is different. Also, these tests all compile on [all versions of GCC since 4.7.1 (including 11.x)](https://godbolt.org/z/G5W1b88Y8), even though AFAIK each one is redeclaring `SomeValue` as "a different type of entity":

```c++
constexpr int SomeValue = 0;

void test1 () { typedef void (SomeValue) (); }
void test2 () { double SomeValue;            }
void test3 () { using SomeValue = char *;    }
void test4 () { void (* SomeValue) ();       }
void test5 () { struct SomeValue { };        }
void test6 () { enum class SomeValue { };    }
```

As a relatively less nonsensical example, this code also fails [from 11.x on](https://godbolt.org/z/5MhrP38qE) in a similar fashion:

```c++
constexpr int SomeValue = 0;

struct SomeClass {
    explicit SomeClass (int) { }
    void operator () () { }
};

void test () {
    SomeClass(SomeValue)();
}
```

Although in this case it's preceded by a vexing-parse warning that also isn't present before 11.x (the fact that the warning is here but not in the above makes sense, the fact that the warning doesn't appear pre-11.x is the interesting bit):

```
<source>: In function 'void test()':
<source>:9:25: warning: empty parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    9 |     SomeClass(SomeValue)();
      |                         ^~
<source>: At global scope:
<source>:9:26: error: 'SomeClass SomeValue()' redeclared as different kind of entity
    9 |     SomeClass(SomeValue)();
      |                          ^
<source>:1:15: note: previous declaration 'constexpr const int SomeValue'
    1 | constexpr int SomeValue = 0;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

*But wait! There's more!*

This code -- which I would have expected to fail on 11.x due to the same parsing ambiguities as above -- compiles just fine on [all those versions of GCC (including 11.x)](https://godbolt.org/z/P5jP7xade):

```c++
constexpr int SomeValue = 0;

auto closure = [] (int) {
    return [] () { };
};

void test () { 
    closure(SomeValue)(); // <-- doesn't cause any problems
}
```

No warnings or anything there.

So... What's going on here? Why is it only a problem for `SomeValue` to be "redeclared as a different kind of entity" in those specific cases, and only since GCC 11.1, and why doesn't `closure(SomeValue)()` suffer the same problem as `SomeClass(SomeValue)()`?

Also what changed? Is GCC correct here? Is it a new bug introduced in GCC 11.x? Or perhaps an old bug that was finally fixed in 11.x? Or not a bug at all and something else changed?

I'm struggling to come up with a consistent explanation.

Comment: Fails to compile with clang, gcc and MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/EzTc7E95b

Comment: `void (SomeValue) ();` is a declaration of a function `SomeValue`.  Functions must have namespace (in this case global) scope, which then clashes with the declaration of `constexpr int SomeValue = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that your first snippet declares a function that exists globally; all your other declarations are of local entities.
(Note that even if the declaration were valid, you couldn't call that function, since it can't exist.)

In the last snippet, `closure` is not a type, so it can't be a declaration.

Comment: Ok; that explains why https://godbolt.org/z/KhfTo1xTa works too, then. I had to think about "a function that exists globally" for a second, still not sure I get it... is `void (X) ()` a synonym for `extern void X ()`? Also what's going on with gcc 11.x's changed behavior then?

Comment: @JasonC They are synonyms in the sense that function declarations are `extern` by default. Re gcc, I suppose that someone finally got around to fixing the bug. It's not a serious problem since it doesn't lead to any misbehaviour, so it's not terribly surprising that it's taken a while. (Also, it is very rare to declare functions locally these days.)

Comment: Ah, if you remove the `constexpr` it actually stops compiling [from 8.x on](https://godbolt.org/z/qPTW7TaET). That definitely seems more like maybe a bug was mostly squished in 8.x and some remnants finally taken case of in 11.x.